# gnu as claims to support extra local symbols with $. Why does this code compile with error claiming symbol is already used?

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu

gnu as supports "extra local symbols" terminated by $. These symbols are undefined with each non-local symbol defined. Yet the following code gives an error saying that symbol .L1$ is being redefined. I tested with both L1$ and .L1$ because some documentation indicated that symbols beginning with L are local.

here is a reference to one document in gnu as:
http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC46

I can't find it in the regular manual, and perhaps that's part of the problem. I thought I saw this. Is this my mistake? Is it no longer supported?

```
    .global f
f:

.L1$:
        mov r0, #1
        bne     .L1$
        bx      lr
        .global g
g:
.L1$:
        mov r0, #1
    bne     .L1$
    bx      lr
```

Comment: The [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Symbol-Names) mentions that this is target specific.  Perhaps it's not supported on ARM?

Comment: You defined  `.L1$` twice in the same compilation unit, which does not make sense to me. I would understand 'local' in terms off the linker, not the assembler/compiler, you still cannot have duplicates in the same code  - my two cents.

Comment: @Frant, if you don't understand the question, why answer it? Read here: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731175576.htm This feature is quite useful. it's like having local variables in functions in C. No, these symbols are not stored in the object.

Comment: Note that the manual you linked (for Ti-GCC on texas-instruments calculators) says that dollar local labels use **`$` *instead of* `:`**.  Even if it was supported on ARM targets, you're just defining normal file-scoped symbols that happen to end with a dollar-sign.  But as Ross points out, they only work with numeric names; they're a special form of *local* labels, which in GAS terminology means number-names only.

Comment: @Dov: Please note that  I did not really answer, I just added a comment, precisely because this was not doing sense to me.  This is sometime a good way lo learn new things from easy going people.

Answer (score 2):

The GNU Assembler doesn't support the "extra local symbols" feature you claim exists.  You've probably been confused by the documented [Dollar Local Labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Dollar-Local-Labels) feature, but this feature doesn't work as you described.

Dollar Local Labels are variation of the [Local Symbol Names](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1) feature, where labels consisting of only digits can be multiply defined.  The Dollar Local Label feature also allows a label consisting of only digits followed by a single dollar sign ($) to be multiply defined.  Reference to these symbols is made by suffixing an `f` or `b` to the label so the assembler knows to look forwards or backwards for the label.  The difference between the two is that Dollar Local Labels become undefined after any subsequent non-local label is defined.

Also note that labels that start with `.L` are not local in the same way as the symbols described in the previous paragraph are.  Labels starting with `.L` can only be defined once and can be referenced from anywhere in the assembler source file. In that sense they're no different than any normal symbol.  What makes them different from normal symbols is that they're not included in the generated object file's symbol table.

Finally, note that the Dollar Local Label feature, in addition to not doing what you want, is also not implemented on ARM targets.  It's also not implemented on x86 targets either. It not really necessary, as the Local Symbol Names feature works just as well.

There is no feature supported by the GNU assembler that treats symbols starting with a non-digit character and ending with a dollar sign any differently on any platform.